# Regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, whitespace, string-matching

Why this regex:

```
[^\s]+
```

...says that this string:

> "user's extension"

isn't exact match?

Comment: Please show some *actual code*.

Comment: `[^\\s]` matches the beginning of the line followed by a whitespace character, 1 or more times. The only problem is that the beginning on the line doesn't occur more than once for a string on one line. try moving the `^` outside the `[]`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No, the `^` means "negation" inside a character class.

Comment: What does this have anything to do with Qt?

Comment: Actually, it is an exact match. It matches whatever the regex says. Isin't that what you want? In Perl "user's extension" =~ /[^\s]+/ matches, exactly.

Comment: @sln: But it matches only the `user's` part of it, not the entire string.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - I would never translate 'exact match' in terms of regex. If a regular expression matches, it matches exactly. This regex matches `user's` exactly. It matches because it must. What it *doesen't* match is well, just another story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex only matches a string that doesn't contain any whitespace. Your matching method appears to apply the regex to the entire string, therefore it fails.

`[abc]` is a character class, meaning "either `a`, `b` or `c`".
`[^abc]` is the inverse of that class meaning "any character except `a`, `b` or `c`".
`\s` means "any whitespace character".
`[^\s]` (which can also be written as `\S`) means "any non-whitespace character".
`+` means "one or more of the preceding token.

Comment: Except that the backslash is escaped, and so it will match white space.

Comment: @jmoreno: No, the double backslash is only for string escaping.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Looking at how my answer was displaying, I guess I'll have to accept that (and delete my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex would match strings only with one or more non-whitespace characters. `"user's extension"` contains matching substrings, but it is not a match itself because of the space character.